# SPF records and rejection based by declaration client IP

Tags: exchange, spf

I use my personal email server one small setup by Microsoft Exchange Online.
I'm not I professional IT but I prefer Exchange for many reason.

Now I use this SPF record:  *v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all*

I sent an email to some and I receive this as answer:
 
*When trying to deliver your message, the mail server at host=EBOSMAILSERVER,from=ebos.com.cy encountered problems with the following addresses:*

For *******@cytanet.com.cy, ubad=0, Site (cytanet.com.cy/[IP]) said: 550 5.7.1 *******@cytanet.com.cy: Recipient address rejected: Please see http://www.openspf.net/Why?s=mfrom;id=*******%40[MyDomain].tld;ip=[IP];r=promitheas3.pri.cytanet.com.cy

For a more detailed explanation see http://netwinsite.com/surgemail/deliver_failed.htm

The openspf.net said: 

*promitheas3.pri.cytanet.com.cy rejected a message that claimed an envelope sender address of ****@mydomain.tld.*

promitheas3.pri.cytanet.com.cy received a message from mail.ebos.com.cy ([IP]) that claimed an envelope sender address of ****@mydomain.tld.

However, the domain mydomain.tld has declared using SPF that it does not send mail through mail.ebos.com.cy (***.***.***.***). That is why the message was rejected.

If I understand correct I must define an "a record" as client. But this email I use it from too many device (laptops, Tablet, Mobile Phones) and also from different ISP.

I think that is a very-very strict rule. What you suggest me to do?
This issue I have it with this specific receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to send mail directly to recipients, however, your SPF record declares that messages can only come from Exchange Online.  In my opinion, you have two options:

1. It appears your messages are coming from mail.ebos.com.cy.  Assuming this is always the case, you could add an entry into your SPF record to account for that.  Your new SPF record would be:`v=spf1 a:mail.ebos.com.cy include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all`.  If this is not always the case, then I would recommend the second option.
2. Send all of your messages through Exchange Online using their published settings at [How to set up a multifunction device or application to send email using Office 365](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn554323(v=exchg.150).aspx) or [Outlook settings for POP and IMAP access for Office 365 for business or Microsoft Exchange accounts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Outlook-settings-for-POP-and-IMAP-access-for-Office-365-for-business-or-Microsoft-Exchange-accounts-7fc677eb-2491-4cbc-8153-8e7113525f6c).  This is going to be your best option, if I am understanding your situation correctly.

Comment: Ι appreciate too much your time. In every device I setup my account as Microsoft Exchange (with autodiscover feature), so I don't have the choice to setup something different from the default option as smtp server. I check again my settings from outlook and i dont see anything about how i send my emails. Btw I have do this test: http://www.mail-tester.com/web-UZCSF1

Comment: The error message in your question explicitly states that the message came from `mail.ebos.com.cy`.  This would not be the case if the only way you send messages is through Outlook setup with Autodiscover.  By what other ways are you sending messages?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is mail.ebos.com.cy and for sure I don't have any crendentials for it (username/password). Daily I use two ways to sent emails, or Outlook 2016 or Windows Phone. 

You believe that is possible a bad server configuration from the receiver? Maybe they use something as middle server (the mail.ebos.com.cy) and so the final server check: 

Who sent me this? The ebos server
What say the SPF records? Outlook.com? Wrong, reject the email.

Comment: I believe the only other scenario is that there is a bad configuration on the recipient's end, as you say.

Comment: Some last, do you believe that if I use Microsoft Exchange Protocol with autodiscover the appropriate SPF record is: v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all

Right?

Comment: Yes.  That is the best SPF record to use.